# how restart when live stream stucks on videojs

Tags: javascript, html, video.js

sometimes my live stream restarts , and there is a spinner on the video like this
[https://i.imgur.com/bHiqemT.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X7Gn2.jpg)
it cant resume if you dont restart yourself,

how can player restart it itself?

i have such code

```
this.on('ended', function() {
      player.src({
            src: stream(),
            type: 'application/x-mpegURL'
    });player.play();
    console.log('end res?');
});
this.on('error', function() {
      player.src({
            src: stream(),
            type: 'application/x-mpegURL'
    });player.play();
    console.log('err res?');
});
```

this works when end or network error.but i want to do same when it just stucks?

Comment: Have you tried loading the video/src before attempting to play it? `.load()`

Comment: no, i have no problem when playing video,somtimes i need to restart the live stream,when i restart player stucks for forever,i want my player restart itself

Comment: When the player is "stuck" does it trigger any of the event listeners? `ended` or `error`?

Comment: no it doesnt , i dont know if it trigger any event i couldnt  find,i couldnt get any support